# i followed the instructions for this if and else, but i keep getting an error

Tags: c

So, I'm trying to make seat available for my booking flight and it showed me the error where 'else' without a previous 'if', can someone help me, I'm just a beginner, thanks!

```
  int seatavailable(int available)
    {
            printf("\n\t\tChose Your Destination United States of America @ Italy @ Indonesia:\n");
            scanf("%s", &available);
    
            if (strcmp(available,"United States of America"));
            {
                printf("\nUnited States of America");
                printf("\n29-04-2019");
                printf("\n1.1200");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 7);
                printf("\n29-04-2019");
                printf("n2. Date\n");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 10);
            }
            else (strcmp(available,"Italy"));
            {
                printf("\nItaly");
                printf("\n15-04-2019");
                printf("\n1.0300");
                printf("\nAvailable Seat: %d", 3);
                printf("\n15_04_2019");
                printf("\n2. Date\n");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 9);
            }
            else (strcmp(available,"Indonesia"));
            {
                printf("\nIndonesia");
                printf("\n05-07-2021");
                printf("\n1.1730");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 3);
                print("\n05-07-2019");
                printf("\n2. Date\n");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 7);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I think you mean `else if`. `else` blocks have no condition in parenthesis.

Comment: if must be `else if( strcmp .... )`

Answer (score 0):

`else` doesn't mean `else if`. You have to write `if` manually to use `else if`.

Also:

- Using `%s` with variable of `int` is wrong. `%s` is for reading string with `char*` passed.
- You have extra `;` in the lines of `if` and `else`.
- The result of `scanf()` should be checked to see if it successfully read something.
- Your function returns `int`, so you should have it return something via `return` statement.

Try this:

```
  int seatavailable(int some_unused_argument)
    {
            char available[128];
            printf("\n\t\tChose Your Destination United States of America @ Italy @ Indonesia:\n");
            if (scanf("%127s", available) != 1) return 0;
    
            if (strcmp(available,"United States of America"))
            {
                printf("\nUnited States of America");
                printf("\n29-04-2019");
                printf("\n1.1200");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 7);
                printf("\n29-04-2019");
                printf("n2. Date\n");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 10);
            }
            else if (strcmp(available,"Italy"))
            {
                printf("\nItaly");
                printf("\n15-04-2019");
                printf("\n1.0300");
                printf("\nAvailable Seat: %d", 3);
                printf("\n15_04_2019");
                printf("\n2. Date\n");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 9);
            }
            else if (strcmp(available,"Indonesia"))
            {
                printf("\nIndonesia");
                printf("\n05-07-2021");
                printf("\n1.1730");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 3);
                print("\n05-07-2019");
                printf("\n2. Date\n");
                printf("Available Seat: %d", 7);
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

This program won't produce compilation error if required headers are included, but `strcmp(available,"United States of America")` will always be non-zero (true) because `%s` stops reading at whitespace and `available` will never be a string containing whitespace characters.